# Python "Function call with parameter: Converting measurements?"

Tags: python, python-3.x, function-calls

I am taking my first programming course, so my apologies if this is a dumb question/possibly classified by the wrong category on this site. One of the exercise problems I am working on is the following:

Define a function print_total_inches, with parameters num_feet and num_inches, that prints the total number of inches. Note: There are 12 inches in a foot. Ex:
   print_total_inches(5, 8) prints:
Total inches: 68

The photo attached is the code that I did along with the error that I received. Any help/resources are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image: My code so far]

Comment: Please do not post images of codec add the code and error message as formatted text *in the question itself*

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your code here, rather than link it in a picture, as you will be more likely to receive help.

Comment: @RayhaneMama Please refrain from adding salutations at the end of posts when OP didn't even add them there.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you. I'll keep that in mind when asking questions in the future!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ thank you. I'll keep that in mind when asking questions in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fails at formatting the input (along with missing the calculations needed).

```
def print_total_inches (num_feet, num_inches):
    print('Total inches:', num_feet * 12 + num_inches)

print_total_inches(5, 8)
```

or

```
def total_inches (num_feet, num_inches):
    return num_feet * 12 + num_inches

print('Total inches:', total_inches(5, 8))
```

should do - and no need for `return` when there's nothing to return.

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_total_inches(num_feet, num_inches):
    totalinches = (12*num_feet) + num_inches
    print('total inches:' + str(totalinches))

print_total_inches(5, 8)
```

You do not need to return, as your function name says `print_total_inches`

Alternatively you can use `format` as well to print

`print('total inches:{0}'.format(total_inches))`

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot. All I had to fix with this code was some picky spacing stuff. This makes way more sense now :)